# ELL's Greatest Hits Page

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I came across the [Stack Exchange's Greatest Hits](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/24/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) blog post on EL&U's meta, and found that ELL has a ["greatest hits" page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits/). This page lists the questions that have received a lot of attention in terms of views and interactions. The list is pretty interesting, and it might be a good idea to check it every so often to make sure that the questions and answers reflect well on the site.

This explanation is at the bottom of the page:

> Questions that got a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback.
>
> The current algorithm divides the number of page views with the total amount of question and answer feedback received (adding a bonus for high view counts), excluding questions with less views than the median :- 186.

The number displayed for the median is dynamic - the last time I checked the page it was down to 172.

Comment: That should read: questions that got a large number of views. :) Also, shouldn't it be **divide by**? What do you mean by "reflect well on the site"?

Comment: @Lambie By “reflect well” I mean that when someone stumbles across them they think “hey, I wonder what other useful stuff this site has” instead of “well that didn’t help”. What sorts of things we might need to do to get a particular question in shape would depend on its current state.

Comment: Well, that blurb needs editing. Thanks for explaining that to me.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, that's not how I would have written it. The page isn't linked anywhere from the user interface though, so I don't think they're doing much with it. It's a little "secret" page I thought others might find interesting.